# ¿Como sumar y condicionar los valores de un formulario hecho en php?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Estoy utilizando un formulario en PHP y necesito validar que la sumatoria de los campos no supere 5, ya intente con JQuery pero no me da resultado. El código que estoy utilizando es

```
$("#formValidate").validate({
    rules: {
        <?php
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM items where not deleted;");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo $row["id"].':{
            min: 0,
            max: 4
            },
            ';
        }
    echo '},';
    ?>
    messages: {
        <?php
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM items where not deleted;");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {  
            echo $row["id"].':{
            min: "Minimo 1 producto",
            max: "Maximo 4 productos"
            },
            ';
        }
    echo '},';
    ?>
    errorElement : 'div',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      var placement = $(element).data('error');
      if (placement) {
        $(placement).append(error)
      } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
      }
    }
 });
```

Como puedo lograr que se valide la sumatoria de los valores de los inputs, y generar un mensaje de error cuando este supere los 5 productos?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Por favor, incluye el HTML del formulario, para que veamos qué campos tiene. También, indica si estás utilizando algún plugin de jQuery, ya que no me suena que haya una función `validate()`. Por último, no mezcles Javascript y PHP. Ejecuta el PHP al principio de todo, mete los valores que necesites en una variable de javascript (con `json_encode()`) y utiliza esta variable en adelante.